# Ryder cloaks while evading

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

When I try to evade, Ryder cloaks. Is this a bug?

It started while I was doing missions on Havarl.

Comment: Huh? What happens when you try evading?

Answer (score 11):

This is not a bug, it's a feature. Cloaking when evading is a perk of the upgraded Infiltrator profile, called Cloak Evades. As you put in more skill points in Combat and Tech, you will upgrade your profile and gain an extra passive perk.

[image: Infiltrator profile]

If you don't like it, the only way to get rid of it is to use a different profile.

Comment: Ohhh.! So that's what it was. I did remember that I activated the infiltrator profile to get rid fight that gaint ass turret in havarl. Ah I'm such an Idiot. I guess I should read those tips careful.. anyway thanks

Comment: @mayurmanudhanya If it was what you were searching for, then think about accepting the answer of Kareen.